# Работа с Объектами

Tags: php

Разбираю текст функцией `simplexml_load_file()`, в итоге получается что то типа:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AminoAcid Object

            [middle-name] => Габриэль
            [last-name] => Верн
            [author] => 
            [book-title] => Двадцать тысяч лье под водой
            [annotation] => 
            [p] => Книга рассказывает о кругосветном путешествии...
            [keywords] => Жюль Верн, Немо, Наутилус, Двадцать тысяч лье под водой
            [date] => 1869-70
            [lang] => ru
            [src-lang] => fr
            [translator] => 
        )

    [1] => AminoAcid Object
        (
           ... 
        )

    [2] => AminoAcid Object
        (
            ...
        )

    ...

)
```

Всё бы ничего, но при выводе строки мешает дефис "-" в тегах. Например:

`$arry[0]->keywords;` - выводит

`$arry[0]->middle-name;` - не выводит

Как можно вывести текст?

Comment: Попробуйте

     $arry[0]['middle-name'];

Вообще я бы заменил - на _

Comment: если так не выведет, то преобразуйте simplexml_object в array, и выводите себе на здоровье, хотя повторюсь - я бы просто изменил - на _

Comment: Не, так не получается. Заменить теги не в моих силах, так что надо как то с этими.

Comment: Ну попробуйте тогда:

    $arry = simplexml_load_file('filePath');
    $arry = (array) $arry;
    echo $arry[0]['middle-name'];

Насколько помню как-то так я делал когда-то

Comment: Получилось, но преобразуется только этот объект. А у мене большая вложенность. И получается, что каждый уровень надо преобразовывать в массив. Сойдёт конечно, но если есть способ преобразовать всё сразу, то предложите пожалуйста.

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К полям объекта можно обращаться так:

```
echo $arry[0]->{'middle-name'};
```

Comment: можно и так, но если с кодом работает несколько разработчиков, то джуны, мягко говоря - не поймут :)

Comment: Ну давайте еще вместо правильного писать всем понятный код)) Процедурный стиль, `$i = $i+1` и тп) Это вроде не такая уж и профи штука, в php много на этом повязано.

    $a = "lol {$b['c']}"; // туда же
    ${'my-super-var!'} = $a; // туда же

Имхо, это надо знать, джунам в том числе.

Comment: Из личного опыта - скажите это джунам :)